# SRSS - Unable to View Reports on Web Service URL - Unable to Vaidate Data

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have just migrated my SSRS instance from a SQL 2008 server to a new 2014 server.  Everything is working OK apart from the ability to view reports in the Report Server web service URL.  This is the link that appears at the bottom of emails to allow users to click and re-run the report.

I can access the reportserver URL and move through the folders but as soon as I try to render a report it fails.  I have created a blank dummy report with no data sources and it is sill doing the same.  If i view these reports via the Reports URL all is ok.  I have HTTPS setup but you can still use the HTTP URL and i have test it on both with same results.

```
library!ReportServer_0-2!f3c!05/19/2019-10:36:56:: e ERROR: Error rending control: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to validate data.
   at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, IVType ivType, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean signData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.EncryptStringWithIV(String s, IVType ivType)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.RuntimeScriptResourceHandler.GetScriptResourceUrlImpl(List`1 assemblyResourceLists, Boolean zip, Boolean notifyScriptLoaded)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.RuntimeScriptResourceHandler.System.Web.Handlers.IScriptResourceHandler.GetScriptResourceUrl(List`1 assemblyResourceLists, Boolean zip, Boolean notifyScriptLoaded)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.RuntimeScriptResourceHandler.System.Web.Handlers.IScriptResourceHandler.GetScriptResourceUrl(Assembly assembly, String resourceName, CultureInfo culture, Boolean zip, Boolean notifyScriptLoaded)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.GetScriptResourceUrl(Assembly assembly, String resourceName, CultureInfo culture, Boolean zip, Boolean notifyScriptLoaded)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlFromName(ScriptManager scriptManager, IControl scriptManagerControl, Boolean zip)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterUniqueScripts(List`1 uniqueScripts)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts()
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
library!ReportServer_0-2!f3c!05/19/2019-10:36:56:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeException: The request has been aborted., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeException: An error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-2-132027317822865767. Most likely, the HTTP request contains an unsupported verb or invalid syntax. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Unable to validate data.
   at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, IVType ivType, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean signData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.EncryptStringWithIV(String s, IVType ivType)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.RuntimeScriptResourceHandler.GetScriptResourceUrlImpl(List`1 assemblyResourceLists, Boolean zip, Boolean notifyScriptLoaded)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.RuntimeScriptResourceHandler.System.Web.Handlers.IScriptResourceHandler.GetScriptResourceUrl(List`1 assemblyResourceLists, Boolean zip, Boolean notifyScriptLoaded)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.RuntimeScriptResourceHandler.System.Web.Handlers.IScriptResourceHandler.GetScriptResourceUrl(Assembly assembly, String resourceName, CultureInfo culture, Boolean zip, Boolean notifyScriptLoaded)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.GetScriptResourceUrl(Assembly assembly, String resourceName, CultureInfo culture, Boolean zip, Boolean notifyScriptLoaded)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlFromName(ScriptManager scriptManager, IControl scriptManagerControl, Boolean zip)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterUniqueScripts(List`1 uniqueScripts)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts()
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Use Notepad to open the web.config file of Report Server and Report Manager. In SSRS 2012, the default location is: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer
 (Note: Please backup the file before modify it.)
2.Add the following  section in the  section:

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911722/en-us

Comment: This link is broken. Is there an updated one?

Answer (score 0):

CAUSE
This problem occurs when the following conditions are true:
The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\fipsalgorithmpolicy
registry subkey is set to 1.
ASP.NET 2.0 uses the RijndaelManaged implementation of the AES algorithm when it
processes view state data. The ReindaelManaged implementation has not been
certified by the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) as
compliant with the Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS). Therefore, the
AES algorithm is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic
algorithms.

WORKAROUND
Important These steps may increase your security risk. These steps may also make
the computer or the network more vulnerable to attack by malicious users or by
malicious software such as viruses. We recommend the process that this article
describes to enable programs to operate as they are designed to or to implement
specific program capabilities. Before you make these changes, we recommend that
you evaluate the risks that are associated with implementing this process in your
particular environment. If you decide to implement this process, take any
appropriate additional steps to help protect the system. We recommend that you use
this process only if you really require this process.

```
To work around this problem, change the configuration in the application-level 
Web.config file. Specify that ASP.NET use the Triple Data Encryption Standard 
(3DES) algorithm to process view state data. 
To do this, follow these steps: 
In a text editor such as Notepad, open the application-level Web.config file.
In the Web.config file, locate the <system.web> section.
Add the following <machineKey> section to in the <system.web> section:
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" 
decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="3DES" decryption="3DES"/>
Save the Web.config file.
Restart the Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) service. To do this, run
```

the following command at a command prompt:
iisreset
Important Theoretically, the 3DES algorithm is less secure than the AES (Rijndael)
algorithm. We recommend that you use the AES algorithm whenever possible to help
secure your system.

Comment: Wayback machine to URL